# How to find $x$ in $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4{x^2}}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation: $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4{x^2}}=1$ and trying to find $x$ value.

I wasn't able to proceed after having common denominator  $\frac{2{x^3}-1}{4x^2}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now have a cubic as (cross multiply by $4x^2$ and then subtract it from both sides):

$$2x^3 - 4x^2 -1 =0$$

Do you know how to solve a [*cubic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots)?

You get one real and two complex solutions.

**Spoiler (Hover if you dare)**

> $x = 2.11208493554430$

Comment: Do you not think the OP has trouble getting to the cubic equation?

Comment: How about when they said "I wasn't able to proceed after having common denominator $\displaystyle \frac{2x^3−1}{4x^2}=1$"?

Comment: Agreed but I am doubting whether the student knows why they can multiply both sides by $4x^2$ and then add $-4x^2$ to both sides... I suppose it is up to the OP to get back to you.

Comment: It is a good observation by you, but that is precisely why I did not give it all away. I also see that the OP had some notion of the concepts by what they did show (they knew enough about common denominator and suc). These days, we seem to attract a lot of get-an-answer and run crowd. Regards